# include libraries that are used in header file of self-made static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, static-libraries

In a static library project I have "myClass.h" that is somehow like below:

```
class myClass{
.
.
#include "tensorflow/....h" //some tensorflow header file
.
.
using tensorflow::Tensor;
.
.
void CopyTensorImage2Cv(tensorflow::Tensor &Tensor);
.
.
}
```

}

and I have "myClass.cpp" that has definition of `CopyTensorImage2Cv()`.

I want to make a static library, so I build the project and get "myClass.lib" successfully.

Now, I make a Console App with source code "test.cpp" to use this lib file.
When I add lib file and copy "myClass.h" next to "test.cpp" and build the project, Visual Studio rises an error that can't understand `#include "tensorflow/....h"` and `"using tensorflow::Tensor"`

What can I do in this case, which I want to use a static library that uses another library in its header file?

Comment: Does the .h file include the entire library? Perhaps it depends on other elements? Are the include paths correct?

Comment: yes, All work correctly with this code when I use it. My question is in case of using this code as a static library.

Comment: Includes templates?

Comment: build a project that only contains necessary header files and myClass.cpp, compile it, you will get an error related to 'main()' but neglect it, you will get myClass.o file(object file) than in the next project after adding all necessary files(header + myClass.h + main() file), link myClass.o file and run the project. This time myClass.o will act as static library.

Comment: @Michael Chourdakis yes

Comment: @udit043 what do you mean by link? How should I link .obj file to project?

Comment: @farshad22 the same way you link xyz.a or xyz.lib file

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,
I used Forward Declaration to avoid using #include in my header file. 
It works for me. 
for more detail you can search about Forward Declaration in header file.
for example in this case I use following code:

```
namespace tensorflow{
      class Tensor;
};
```